# Does the Civilization IV exe contain Beyond the Sword updates

Tags: civilization-4

I recently bought Civilization IV Complete on Gamersgate and installed it.

After installation I got 3 start options.
- Civilization IV Complete
- Civilization IV Beyond The Sword
- Civilization IV Warlords

My question is if I start the "Civilization IV Complete" exe does that contain the add functionality of BTW and Warlords, or is it Civilization IV Vanilla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd choose Beyond the Sword to play the BTS content and Warlords to play the Warlords content. Thus, you'd pick "Complete" to play Vanilla Civ IV, similar to how Steam gives you n number of launch shortcuts depending on which expansions you have installed.

Comment: Ok, thanks, that's what I feared. The problem is that my BTS exe wont start :(

Comment: Time to check the support forums for Gamer's Gate.

Comment: I got BTS working by updating to the lastest patch 3.19. All is well